# R: Error in textConnection: all connections are in use

Tags: r

I have an user defined function:

```
xml2csv = function(inputFile,outputFile) {
  X <- read.table(inputFile, header = FALSE, fill = TRUE,sep=" ")

  #step1: seperate cell by one  or more space
  Y <- concat.split.multiple(X, as.vector(colnames(X)), "")

  #step2: seperate cell by ":"
  Z <- concat.split.multiple(Y, as.vector(colnames(Y))[-c(1:2)], ":")

  #delete repeat rows
  U=Z[!Z[,1] == "__REPEAT__", ]

  #convert factor column as character
  V <- data.frame(lapply(U, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  W = V
  W[is.na(W)] = 0
  write.csv(W, outputFile, quote = F, row.names = F)
}
```

It works perfectly fine for small inputFile; when the input file is big (>2000kb), the following error appears:

```
Error in textConnection(text, encoding = "UTF-8") :   all connections are in use
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What package does `concat.split.multiple` come from?

Comment: Looks like it's from http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splitstackshape/index.html

Comment: It seems like a bug in @AnandaMahto's splitstackshape package. Looking at the src code of `splitstackshape:::read.concat`, a `textConnection` is opened (perhaps multiple times), but not closed. And R does not allow for opening too many connections (`?connections`: *A maximum of 128 connections can be allocated*)

Comment: You may want to look at my [`cSplit` function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733) as an alternative to `concat.split.multiple`. It will be faster and shouldn't have the problem you describe. However, I would still like to try to solve this problem in `read.concat`. Can you share a sample file with me? You can find my email address at my GitHub page.

Comment: Alternatively, try installing the "devel" version of "splitstackshape" from GitHub and let me know if that solves your problem. `library(devtools); install_github("splitstackshape", "mrdwab", ref = "devel")`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell what's going on exactly (your error is not reproducible!), but my money is on it's a bug/limitation of `concat.split.multiple` when you have too many columns in `X`, since

- it calls `concat.split` on each of the columns in `lapply`,
- which uses `textConnection` internally,
- which creates a temporary file,
- which uses a file handler,
- which is a limited resource in most operating systems :).

Comment: @gagolews, thanks for the bug-report and the link to this question and answer. Victor K, +1 for the explanation.